# Are there any functions or formulas that help find patterns in sequences of numbers in different rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is my spreadsheet for anyone to access and see the full data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LoAzz39qs0rL6d9f98QzCBrNRWDX_Oa_jj-hv5fgjL8/edit?usp=sharing

Each line has the name of the game and a sequence of values, currently the only thing I can extract from this is to sum the values and create an average:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",(B1:B+C1:C+D1:D+E1:E+F1:F)/5))
```

Data example:

```
Everton x West Ham      86  8   37  20  18  28
Man Utd x Aston Villa   61  30  42  60  24  15
Man Utd x Aston Villa   58  84  29  39  30  42
Man Utd x Aston Villa   40  47  25  17  32  19
Tottenham x Leeds       50  18  1   5   26  22
```

But I would like to find some kind of pattern in these numbers, something that demonstrates something that appears or happens on most lines to understand if they have anything in common.

Is there any function or forumula that can give me something like that?

I thought about creating a column of unique values:

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B1:F))
```

And then count the number of times each number appears:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(B1:F),
                                    UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B1:F))))
```

But that seemed so superficial to me and I thought I'd ask here in the community that has great spreadsheet geniuses.

**EXAMPLE OF USE:**

In a hypothetical example I could say that each of these values means the strength of a shot that the athletes made before they managed to score a goal. So let's say column B was the fifth shot before goal, Column C was the fourth shot before goal, Column D was the third shot before goal, and so on.

I would like to find some pattern in these 5 numbers of each row, so that when any live game produces this pattern, it alerts me so I can do a study of goals produced from this pattern in relation to how often does it happen during matches.

Comment: Tried the "Explore" option?

Comment: Hello @TheMaster how are you? I hope everything is good to you. The explore option is the one we found in ```ALT + SHIFT + X```, correct? I'll take a look now, I didn't know about this option, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm fine :) Don't remember the keyboard shortcut,but the explore button on the bottom right. Your question is a bit vague as well. What output were you expecting? If you're looking for direct insights or machine learning pattern, I can't think of any thing other than "Explore" feature. You will have better luck with python though. (About sharing spreadsheets, if you didn't know, [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private)

Comment: @TheMaster I will think of some additionals to make the question clearer in scope. Thank you for the tip about the link to the spreadsheet, I've already changed the link using a fictitious email that I created just for questions here in the community.

Comment: @TheMaster I added at the end of my question, an example of use to facilitate understanding, I really lacked a notion of use in my question.

Comment: There are some predicting functions like [`LINEST`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094249?hl=en), `TREND`, `GROWTH`, `LOGEST`. But you would need some statistical knowledge.

Comment: hello @BrondbyIF, have you tried the predicting functions suggested by TheMaster? moreover, how would the _expected_ column look like?

Comment: Hello @ale13 how are you?  I'm studying about the functions that he indicated, to try to understand how I can apply and use them, as I don't have enough knowledge to do so.  About the expected column, actually I would like to find some pattern in these 5 numbers of each row, so that when any live game produces this pattern, it alerts me so I can do a study of goals produced from this pattern in relation to how often does it happen during matches.

Comment: If my example in my question wasn't very good because of my poor English, feel free to edit it in a way that better explains my need, I appreciate it and I don't think it's bad if you edit, it's important to make it as clear as possible.  My English can play tricks from time to time.

Comment: great, thanks for the details! however, how would the pattern look like for the first and second row for instance?